# Counting set partitions with partition and subset permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, set-partition

I'm wondering how can I count partitions and subset permutations.

Let's say I'm counting on object `[1,2,3]`.

Desired outcome is below:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 3, 2]]
[[2, 1, 3]]
[[2, 3, 1]]
[[3, 1, 2]]
[[3, 2, 1]]
[[1], [2, 3]]
[[1], [3, 2]]
[[2, 3], [1]]
[[3, 2], [1]]
[[1, 2], [3]]
[[2, 1], [3]]
[[3], [1, 2]]
[[3], [2, 1]]
[[2], [1, 3]]
[[2], [3, 1]]
[[1, 3], [2]]
[[3, 1], [2]]
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1], [3], [2]]
[[2], [1], [3]]
[[2], [3], [1]]
[[3], [1], [2]]
[[3], [2], [1]]
```

So, for each set partition I permute the sets and permute the elements in each set.

I'm aware I can use (ordered) Bell number to accomplish the task but I can't seem to find the mapping to get the permutations of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a set of size $n$, there are $2^{n-1} n!$ of these objects.  That's because you can generate one of these objects by the following process.

- first, take a permutation of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.  There are of course $n!$ ways to do this.
- then, decide which elements are the first element of a new block.  There are $2^{n-1}$ ways to do this, because the first element in the permutation must be the first element of a new block and each following element either is or is not the first element of a new block.

For example, corresponding to the permutation $231$ you have in your list $2^{3-1} = 4$ objects:

```
[[2, 3, 1]]
[[2, 3], [1]]
[[2], [3, 1]]
[[2], [3], [1]]
```

and similarly for each of the other five permutations of $123$, giving a total of $4 \times 6 = 24$ of these permuted set partitions.

Comment: Beautiful. The concept of set partitions is unnecessary. The sequence contains all partitions of a particular permutation but does not depend on it. I guess there's some interesting identity containing the Bell number.